# Cakephp 2.1 naming convensions issue in version change

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

I have just installed CakePHP 2.1. And just see that the naming convention of its is just change lot from the older version which making me crazy.

Like it was `app/controllers` while now it is `app/Controller` same way

`app/models` - `app/Model`

`app/views`  - `app/View`

I know there must be some advantage on doing this. But my problem is when I use the cake bake it is creating directory in the same old fashion i.e. `controllers/models/views`. Which is no more accessible from the URL & obviously will throw an error.

Is anyone there who has face the same issue ? Is there any solution that cake bake also use the same conventions ?

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can always use explicit paths:

```
/path/to/app_dir>..\lib\Cake\Console\cake bake
```

from your APP dir of the current cake project.
this is foolprove and always works with the right cake version.

I do it this way and use a shortcut on my keyboard to print this (up to "cake") on a single key stroke.

Comment: Fantastic ! Trick works ...still i wonder to set it to default...Thanks !!

Comment: If you want to set it as default, read the part about setting the environment path (both 2.x and 1.3 available): http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/31/freshly-baked-cake2-0-tips/

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the change is to be able to better autoload files based on their kind (using App::uses('User', 'Model'); and later , when namespaces are introduced (3.0?) they can be loaded a lot more easy because you will call a class then like for example: "new \Cake\Model\User();"

About your bake problem: Make sure your environment is pointing to the correct "cake" shell file. I'm pretty sure yours is still pointing to the old 1.3 "cake" shell.

Comment: Thanks ! Ya environment pointing is possible .. But I checked it is right..though in console it is showing `Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.7 Console`... I am confused

Comment: It can't be right if its showing 1.3. The path to the cake shell has changed from 1.3 to 2.0. Double check it.

Comment: Yes it was wrong i apologies....actually i installed cake scripts with the command `apt get cake-scripts` it installed cake 1.3 console to /usrr/share/php/cake...how to set it to cake 2.0 lib ?

Comment: The book will tell you http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#adding-cake-to-your-system-path It might be somehow different depending on the mood of your linux flavor.