# How to bake cakephp 2.0 application on windows with wamp

Tags: windows, cakephp, command, cakephp-2.0

I want to bake cake php project on Windows system. I'm using wamp server for PHP  mysql.
I've gone through the video casting on the cakephp site. And did set up the environment setup.

After giving command "cake" as per the demo,Finally I got a message saying

> 'php' is not recognized as internal or external command. operable program or batch file.

Please help me in baking cake php 2.0 project in Windows system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the path to the php.exe into your system variables.

Right-click on "My Computer" --> Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> Environment Variables --> path var

Btw: Please, raise your aceept rate...

Comment: Ya did that set-up. Thats what i mean "environment setup". Its not working for me.

Comment: I'm not using xampp I'm using wamp. And the error message seems to be my windows is not able to detect PHP in my system. It saying "php is not recognized as internal or external command. operable program or batch file."

Comment: Come on, that´s your windows experience and doesn't depends from xampp or wamp You have to put the path to your php.exe in the environment variables in windows. I explained it to you.  What's so difficult? BTW: You could use Google. There are a lot of pages in the Internet that explain your problem... And if you can`t manage it use the tipp from mark

Comment: Okay thanks for making me understanding... I was adding a path for the app/console not for the php.exe. Thanks a lot. @mika

Comment: @Mika, although technically correct, if helping others without the same experience as you elicits the above thrashing, I'd suggest refraining from "helping". People come here for help, not to be flogged for not already knowing.

Comment: @Mike S. Nowadays, the main problem is that people don´t read the documentation or use a search engine. They don´t read the answers given carefully...and ask again. You can watch this behaviour in every forum. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

see my answer on this post:
[Cakephp 2.1 naming convensions issue in version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715480/cakephp-2-1-naming-convensions-issue-in-version-change/9719198#9719198)

using the explicit path via shortcut is the fastest method and doesnt need any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**this article**](http://www.nurelm.com/themanual/2012/01/30/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/). You can run bake command.

1. Open `Computer` under your Windows Start menu.
2. Right-click the `Computer` window, and select `Properties`.
3. You will be brought to the Control Panel’s System window. We’ll need to change our 
   environment variables under `Advanced System Settings`, which you can select from the left column menu in this window.
4. Select the `Advanced`tab on the System Properties window.
5. Click the `Environment Variables…` button.
6. In the System Variables box, find the `Path` variable and click `Edit…`.
7. If there isn’t one already, add a semicolon to the end of the current `Path` variable (a semicolon is used to separate variables).
8. At the end of your Path variable add

   `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\;c:\wamp\www\order_system\app\Console\;` 
    And click `OK` to save your changes.

(The first path should point  to your installation of PHP, and second variable should point to the `app\Console` location of the project that you are developing)