# Find PHP version on windows command line

Tags: php, windows, command, version

I just tried to know version of my PHP from windows command typing,
`C:\> php -v`
But it is not working. It says `php is not recognized as internal or external command`.

Comment: Also [that PHP error windows commandline related: How to bake cakephp 2.0 application on windows with wamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748506/how-to-bake-cakephp-2-0-application-on-windows-with-wamp) - also there are thousands of questions with the same error description (just the name differes), please use the search before asking.

Comment: @hakre I am sorry.I apologized.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

In command prompt type below

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\php
```

Where C:\path\to\php is the folder where your `php.exe` file is located. After this run

```
C:\>php -v
```

than you will see something like

```
PHP 7.3.6 (cli) (built: May 29 2019 12:11:00)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you find that when you restart your computer, this solution will not work anymore:

Set the Path like as following:

> **Step 1** - Click on the `Windows` icon

[image]

> **Step 2** - Click on the `Settings` icon

[image]

> **Step 3** - Click on `System`

[image]

> **Step 4** - Click on `About`

[image]

> **Step 5** - Click on `System info`

[image]

> **Step 6** - Click on `Advanced system settings`

[image]

> **Step 7** - Click on `Environment variables...`

[image]

> **Step 8** - Select `Path` row and then click `Edit`

[image]

> **Step 9** - Click `New` and then click `Browse`, then in the next panel which will open you need to select the folder you want in the `Path`. For the initial premise of this guide i will add the folder `C:\Users\NewFolderInPath`♥
>
> **Note**: Replace your PHP installed path(e.g:`C:\Program Files\php`) with the above path ♥.

[image]

> **Step 10** - Click `OK` and click every `OK` button you will encounter to close every previous windows.

[image]

Comment: @crytic What is PATH=%PATH% ?

Comment: @ntf [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832496/command-prompt-how-to-add-a-set-path-only-for-that-batch-file-executing)

Comment: @crytic I run the command with going to path that my php.exe.Thanks

Comment: this person deserves a medal for taking the time to take all these screenshots <3

Comment: Shortcut is press window button type environment.... open these dialogues and proceed.

Comment: Also you can write Environment variables in window search and cont. from step 7 from above.

Comment: it can be also in System Variables

Answer (score 28):

You just need to find out where is your PHP folder.

- If you are using XAMPP or WAMP then you will see a php folder.
- You just need to go into the php folder using your cmd using command

> cd \xampp\php               (FOR XAMPP)
>
> cd \wamp\php                (FOR WAMP)

- And then just type in this command

> php -v

- Then you will see something like

> PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 20:55:40)
> Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 9):

1. First open your cmd
2. Then go to php folder directory, Suppose your php folder is in xampp folder on your c drive. Your command would then be:

   ```
   cd c:\xampp\php
   ```
3. After that, check your version:

   ```
   php -v
   ```

This should give the following output:

> PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2017 00:17:00) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

I have uploaded a youtube video myself about checking the version of PHP via command prompt in Bangla: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVkhD_tv9ck

Answer (score 6):

Go to c drive and run the command as below

C:\xampp\php>php -v

Answer (score 4):

xampp control panel->shell->type php-v 
you get the version of php of your xampp installed

DB(mariadb/mysql)version
type localhost/phpmyadmin in url click enter
click on sql
type   select version();
enter to get the mysql or mariaDb version

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely that php is not in your specified path.

Try to issue the php command with the full path, for example:

`C:\> "C:\Program Files\php\php.exe" -v`

*Please note, that this is just an example, your php installation might be in a different directory.*

Answer (score 3):

Just create a php file and write the code

```
<?php
echo phpversion();
?>
```

and open the file in any browser. It will show the php version installed in your system.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 : Open CMD

Step 2 : Go to C:/xampp/php or  htdocs path:/

step 3 :  Type  "php -v "

Result php version

Answer (score 2):

For Beginners to anything php, it is usually stored in the C:/ path folder of your PC (My Computer).

==On Windows==
1.Click Start Menu button
2.Type **cmd** and press enter to select the first program/application that responds to your search result.
A black window terminal will appear, this is known as a **Command Line Interpreter**
3.In the Terminal Window (Application) Type **cd c:** and press enter
4.Now type **php -v** and press enter

and viola there you'll have the current php version that is installed in your machine

Answer (score 2):

Easy Method is:
Just copy the file cmd.exe from c:/windows/system32/ and paste it to C:\xampp\php\
and run it,
when the cmd opens type " php -v " without quotes and hit enter...
you will get your php version..
thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Open command prompt
2. Locate directory using cd C:/Xampp/php
3. Type command php -v

You will get your php version details

Answer (score 1):

For me, the PHP path traversed from **php5.6.25** (or php7) installation folder, through wamp folder, bin and php...

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25>

In similar way other providers like WAMP/XAMPP on windows have PHP installed under `<provider-base-dir>\bin\php` directory (even multiple PHP version come from there.

On windows, to know from where your PHP is being executed use

`where php`

or if server is already running create a PHP file to know more about running PHP using phpversion as below

```php
<?php
echo phpversion();
```

BONUS: Sometimes, PHP is not present in windows path, you can add PHP path to Windows environment PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open cmd
2. Type php -v

Output : PHP 5.6.30

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to, just click on the WAMP icon on task bar 
and Go to PHP >Version, version will be displayed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This how I check php version

PS C:\Windows\system32> `php -version`

Result:

```
PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 19 2018 23:44:15) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

PS C:\Windows\system32>

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to worry it's easy

If you are using any local server like Wamp, Xampp then Go to this Steps

1. Go to your drive
2. Check xampp or wamp server that you installed
3. Inside that check php, if you got then go for next step
4. You will find php.exe, 
   Once you get php.exe then you are done. 
   Just type the path like below, here i am using XAMPP and type v for checking version and you are done.

   C:>"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -v

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the `xampp` is installed in your `c` drive then try the below commonds first open cmd and then
type

```
cd c:
```

then

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -v
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure where php is installed on your system, try:

```
.\php -v
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32101078)