# CakePHP cake bake all error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, console

When I run cake bake all then I receive the error messages shown below. Is it my path?

Path on windows:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin;C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\app\Console
```

Error message:

```
 Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.6 Console
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 App : www
 Path: C:\wamp\www\
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 Bake All
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 Warning Error: include_once(C:\wamp\www\Config\database.php): failed to open str
 eam: No such file or directory in [C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Model\Conne
 ctionManager.php, line 68]

 Warning Error: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\Config\database.php'
 for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib;.;C:\php\pear') in [C:
 \wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 68]

 Error: The datasource configuration "default" was not found in database.php
 #0 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php(94): Connection
 Manager::_getConnectionObject('default')
 #1 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(862): Co
 nnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
 #2 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(800): Mo
 delTask->getAllTables('default')
 #3 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(888): Mo
 delTask->listAll('default')
 #4 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\Command\BakeShell.php(149): ModelTa
 sk->getName('default')
 #5 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(386): BakeShell->all()
 #6 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(177): Shell->ru
 nCommand('all', Array)
 #7 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispa
 tcher->dispatch()
 #8 C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\app\Console\cake.php(41): ShellDispatcher::run(Array
 )
 #9 {main}

 C:\wamp\www>
```

Let me know if I need to show anything else. Thanks.

Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me so much code so I typed this sentence to make the editor happy.

Comment: your path which is - `Path: C:\Documents and Settings\The RAYGUN\` is incorrect should be path to your working cake project directory

Comment: Also check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715480/cakephp-2-1-naming-convensions-issue-in-version-change

Comment: I changed my directory, updated my error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you `path` it is incorrect !

Change it to

`C:\wamp\www\cakephp_bake\app\` (i.e. to your app directory)

from

`C:\wamp\www\`